# How to shrink Java ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, android, local-storage, fileoutputstream

I have to store a list of `Serializable` Objects that contains various nested lists of other Objects with many fields,
I have noticed that using a normal `ObjectOutputstream` to store this list requires lot of space also for few entries.

Is there a way to automatically shrink the serializable object before the storage? (without change my Object structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try compressing the object before you store it using a `GZIPOutputStream`.